# Can I change the render order of tpl.php files

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

Can I change the render order of tpl.php files.

e.g. i have a field--x.tpl.php and a field--y.tpl.php and i want to render field--y.tpl.php first how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
function THEME_preprocess(&$variables,$hook) {}
```

create a new element in `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']`
with value `field__y` as below

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = ''
```

Read more for [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

You will get an idea